# How to compile Cython using C++ to get shared object (*.so) files

Tags: python, cython, distutils, cythonize

I am working on some Cython code that uses some C++ standard library data structures, and I am able to compile the code to get *.cpp files. I am doing this using distutils with a setup script (see code). However right now I am not able to generate *.so files, and I am not sure why. Before I needed any of the C++ data structures, the setup script was able to generate *.so files and *.c files. Now it simply generates *.cpp files and I am not able to import them in the rest of my python scripts.

My setup script was made following along with this documentation: 
https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/source_files_and_compilation.html

The extra compilation arguments and language arguments allow the compilation of Cython that includes c++

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize
from distutils.extension import Extension
import numpy

extensions=[
    Extension("mesh",
              sources=["optimized_mesh.pyx"],
              include_dirs=[numpy.get_include()],
              language="c++",
              extra_compile_args=["-stdlib=libc++"])
]

setup(
    ext_modules=cythonize(extensions)
)
```

I expect the output to be a *.cpp file and a *.so file, but so far I am only able to get a *.cpp file.

EDIT:

I found out what was happening, the first argument in `Extension` is the name of the shared object file being created. I was looking for shared object files with the names of the sources.

Comment: The output of what? What was the command?

Comment: Maybe try adding `-fPIC -shared` to compile tags, this is how you'd usually compile a shared lib.

Comment: The code shown is in a script called "setup.py", and the command is 'python setup.py build_ext --inplace'

Comment: @AdamTL I tried adding `-fPIC -shared` to the `setup.py` file but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

The first argument in `Extension` defines the name of the shared object that will be created. If there are multiple sources for compilation, then individual shared object files will not be created for each of those sources, although individual `*.c` or `*.cpp` files will be created.